# Inline images (Content-ID or CID) not always load properly in Gmail?

Tags: c#, image, email, gmail, email-attachments

I have an email with several dozens small images (less than 1kb each). All these images are embedded in email as inline attachments, meaning, they are displayed right in the email body. Everything works as expected, but sometimes some of the images are not loaded. If you reload the page it helps, but other images might be failed to load.

I don't see any possible reasons behind this issue.
MIME headers for the attachments look nice to me (there are few below)

```
----boundary_7_00d60d6d-0799-4fc8-827c-2712420063e2
Content-Type: image/png; name=questiontablesparklinecid4
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-ID: <questiontablesparklinecid4@mydomain.com>


----boundary_7_00d60d6d-0799-4fc8-827c-2712420063e2
Content-Type: image/png; name=questiontablesparklinecid5
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-ID: <questiontablesparklinecid5@mydomain.com>
```

The code to send email is general C# code using System.Net.Mail standard lib, nothing special.

```
foreach (var image in exportResult.Images)
{
    using var stream = await _fileGateway.ReadAsStream(image.ImageUrl);

    var memoryStream = CopyStreamIntoMemory(stream);

    string fileName = image.ImageCID.Substring(0, image.ImageCID.IndexOf('@'));

    var attachment = new Attachment(memoryStream, fileName);
    attachment.ContentId = image.ImageCID;
    attachment.ContentType = new ContentType("image/png");
    // Mark the attachment as embedded so it isn't shown as a regular attachment
    attachment.ContentDisposition!.Inline = true;
    attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
    
    message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
```

That's how the issue looks like
[image: example of the issue]

The most important for me here is that page reloading makes failed images to load correctly and some previously correctly loaded images to fail. For me, it looks like network issue or something related to balancer, etc. Though I'm not aware of real cause of the issue nor I'm not sure how Google serves these images for me underneath